# Rotate a mouse cursor icon using CSS

Tags: css, rotation, resize, mouse-cursor

I have an object that can be resized and rotated.

The object can be resized with 8 different 'handles': s,se,ne,n,nw,w,se
I have set the cursor on the handles with the built in cursors: s_resize, n_resize etc.

The problem is that when the object is rotated the resize cursor does not reflect the direction of the resize handle.

What I need to do is somehow rotate the cursor by the object's angle.

Is there some method using CSS to do this?

I'd hate to use custom cursor icons for each angle...

Comment: I ended up using a double arrow cursor. Then I used 45 versions of that cursor each rotate by 1 degree. Its not optimal, but thats the best I could find

Answer (score 2):

There are also standard cursors for northeast, northwest, southeast and southwest:

```
cursor: ne-resize (an arrow pointing northeast)
cursor: nw-resize (an arrow pointing northwest)
cursor: se-resize (an arrow pointing southeast)
cursor: sw-resize (an arrow pointing southwest)
```

See http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3470321.

If these are good enough I'm afraid you will probably have to use custom images as icon, e.g:

```
.custom {
   cursor: url(images/my-cursor.png), auto;
}
```

Comment: Although the northeast, northwest, southeast and southwest cursors are rotated. they are rotated by a fixed 45 degree angle. I would like to rotate the cursors by an arbitrary angle 0-359